# Solving system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of ordinary differential equations

$$x_1'=-7x_1-9x_2+9x_3+e^{-t}$$
$$x_2'=3x_1+5x_2-3x_3+2e^{-t}+e^t$$
$$x_3'=-3x_1-3x_2+5x_3+3e^t$$
with initial values
$$x_1(0)=1, x_2(0)=0, x_3(0)=0$$

I don't know how to approach this problem. It is even asking to use the Method of Undetermined Coefficients/Method of Variation of Parameters. I can't see examples from the web that has a similar set up like this one.

Comment: @Moo I was only able to solve for the homogeneous part of the solution, I'm still struggling to solve for the non-homogeneous part using MUC.

Answer (score 0):

the homogeneous part comes with a matrix $A$ of constant coefficients. The matrix diagonalizes.

If you can find invertible $Q$ such that
$$ Q^{-1} D Q = A,  $$
then
$$  e^{At} = Q^{-1} e^{Dt} Q $$

Next, if an inhomogeneous part, such as the added $e^t$ has coefficient of $t$ that is not an eigenvalue of the matrix, you can just add it on. If, such as $e^{-t},$ the coefficient of $t$ really is an eigenvalue, usually we need to try $t e^{-t},$ possibly $t^2 e^{-t},$

Comment: Hi, I don't really get what you're saying. Do you have any quick reference?

Comment: @PauloVictorio run an online search for:  ordinary differential equations and jordan normal form